# Rotate Image in Button on Click

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I want the image in the button to rotate +90 degrees or -90 degrees (dependent on the current angle) when the button is clicked. I tried a few solutions, but I only could make the whole button rotate instead of only the image inside it.

Here's the code I have so far (style attributes etc. omitted for readability):

```
<Button Width="110">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Options" />
        <Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Source="../../Images/gt.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="90" Duration="0:0:5" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This is what the button looks like (the little arrow should point down when I click once, and then point right when I click again:

[image: This is what the button looks like]

Anyone has an idea?

Edit: .NET 4.0, using Visual Studio 2010. Oh, and solving this "code-behind" is not an option.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Are you using Expression Blend?

Comment: @Jens .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Hmm.. tricky =) May I ask why code behind is not an option? This could be done without having to repeat the code for every button, using a ValueConverter, by sub-classing button or attached behaviors.

Comment: @Jens Code behind is not an option because I use Caliburn Micro MVVM. Said that, a ValueConverter could work because I can refer to converters from within XAML.

Comment: Try naming the Image and use TargetName property value = name of the Image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that Image will never receive the Button.Click event, since it bubbles only to the button's ancestors not to its descendents. To observe any effect, you'd need to trigger on e.g. MouseDown.

One way to achieve this effect would be to use a ToggleButton instead of a Button and modify its "pressed" state to rotate the arrow. Loosy, this would look like this:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Options">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowImage">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter Height="100"/>
                            <Image x:Name="ArrowImage" Width="48" Height="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Image.RenderTransform>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: That worked - after some minor changes. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image` does not trigger the event, you could try to name the `Button` and set the [`EventTrigger.SourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.sourcename.aspx)

Comment: Tried that already, but it gives an error message "No element MyFirstButton found in Image" - assuming I named the button "MyFirstButton". I tried both "Name" and "x:Name" on the button.